# Handling multiplayer operations in C#

Tags: architecture

I would like to know how do experienced c# developers structure their multiplayer messages and operations.

Basically , in my project every UDP message is translated into an operation and I have to decide what will it trigger. Here is my current structure:

```
switch(newOperation.code){
  case MessageCode.Position:
    MessageHandler.instance.PositionUpdate(newOperation);
    break;
  case MessageCode.NewPlayerJoined:
    MessageHandler.instance.PlayerJoin(newOperation);
```

Basically , for each operation I'm creating an enum and a function that will handle the received packets.

Is there a more maintainable solution?

Comment: This solution is good. You can enhance it by using dictionary (or array) with MessageCode as keys and delegates to method as values. And use [PacketHandler(MessageCode.Position)] attributes over methods that will handle operations.

Comment: @Kikaimaru Would you like to show me an example and post it in the answers? If it seems maintainable I will mark it. Best regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can annotate your packet handler methods like this

```
[PacketHandler(OpCodes.CMSG_LOGIN_REQUEST)]        
public static void OnLoginRequest(Client client, ClientLoginRequestPacket packet)
{    
   // Do stuff
}
```

And then have dictionary of opcodes and handlers and invoke them. So no big switch at cost of dictionary (or array) lookup and one additional method call.

This is how you register handlers

```
Dictionary<OpCode, IPacketHandler> _packetHandlers;


var types = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes();
foreach (var type in types)
{
    foreach (var method in type.GetMethods(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static))
    {
        PacketHandlerAttribute attribute = (PacketHandlerAttribute)method.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(PacketHandlerAttribute), false).SingleOrDefault();
        if (attribute != null)
        {
            OpCodes opCode = attribute.OpCode;

            Type packetType = method.GetParameters()[1].ParameterType;
            Delegate del = Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(Action<,>).MakeGenericType(typeof(Client), packetType), method);
            IPacketHandler handler = (IPacketHandler)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof (PacketHandler<>).MakeGenericType(packetType), del);

            _packetHandlers.Add(opCode, handler);
        }   
    }
}
```

Additional PacketHandler class is nescessary to cast your IPacket to concerete packet type

```
public interface IPacketHandler
{
    void Invoke(Clientclient, IPacket packet);
}

public class PacketHandler<T> : IPacketHandler where T: IPacket
{
    public Action<Client, T> Handler;

    public PacketHandler(Action<Client, T> handler)
    {
        this.Handler = handler;
    } 
    public void Invoke(Client client, IPacket packet)
    {
        Handler(client, (T) packet);
    }
}
```